# Resolve host name sometimes fails

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am adding some features to a cross-domain (6 domains with trust) intranet within a large organisation. 
The system is based on ASP.NET VB (.net 4.0) and is sat on IIS6 on a 2008 R2 sever.

I am using

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST")).HostName
```

to resolve the Hostname to use for logging.

However on SOME machines (always the same ones) this fails. 
Also all machines on ONE domain fail to deliver a hostname. 
This is not browser-dependent.

What could cause this?

Comment: Firewall, Proxy, Anti-virus, etc.

Comment: ^^ ok, I'm interested to know how those could block host name resolution of an otherwise fully functional intranet system...

Comment: How about using [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Microsoft Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) or even [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to investigate further?

Comment: See how `GetHostByAddress` is written, also you can turn on network tracing to get more details on error, may be that can help. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/DNS.cs,2b203858e50ee844